# How to remove object by property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to remove the object by property in nested array object

I have whole list of object in `sampleobj`, compare each id with `apitrans, apifund`, if success is false, remove obj in sampleobj

Remove the object if the success is false, in sampleobj.

I have tried:

````
var result = sampleobj.foreach(e=>{
   if(e.id === "trans" && apitrans.success== true){
      Object.assign(e, apitrans);
   }
  if(e.id === "fund" && apifund.success== true){
      Object.assign(e, apifund);
   }

  // if success false remove the object.
})

//inputs scenario 1
var sampleobj=[{
    id: "trans",
    amount: "100",
    fee: 2
   },
   {
    id: "fund",
    amount: "200",
    fee: 2
   }]
var apitrans = 
  {
   success: true,
   id: "trans",
   tamount: "2000",
   fee: "12"
  }
var apifund =
  {
   success: false,
   id: "fund",
   tamount: "4000",
   fee: "10"
  } 

//inputs scenario 2 how to do same if property name differs
if error, status error, or success false remove obj in sampleobj

var sampleobj=[{
    id: "trans",
    amount: "100",
    fee: 2
   },
   {
    id: "fund",
    amount: "200",
    fee: 2
   },
{ id: "insta", amount: "400", fee: 2 }
]

var apitrans = {success: true,id: "trans",tamount: "2000",fee: "12"}
var apiinsta = { errors: [{code:"error.route.not.supported"}],id: "insta",tamount: "2000",fee: "12"}
var apifund = { status: "error", id: "fund", tamount: "4000", fee: "10" }

var sampleobj=[{
//Expected Output
result: [
  {
    id: "trans",
    amount: "100",
    fee: 2
  }
]```
````

Comment: You can use `filter` e.g. ` const result = sampleobj.filter(o=>o.id===apitrans.id && !apitrans.success)`. Change above condition accordingly. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: can you explain more..? and tell us what have you tried so far because i am not getting your question you want to compare sampleobj arr with  both obj.both objs have ids which is present in an array (id-fund n id-trans)

Comment: @the_ultimate_developer I have updated the post, added what i have tried

Comment: @the_ultimate_developer I need to compare `apitrans with sampleobj and apifund with sampleobj if success false remove the obj in sampleobj`

Comment: @sowmiya yep understood and have posted my answer

Comment: @the_ultimate_developer thanks a lot how to do same for input scenario 2 updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to remove elements from array.

- Create a helper function(`func`) which takes two objects as parameter and compare `id` property of both and check `success` property of one of them.
- Then use `filter()` of the given array and put both given objects array `[apitrans,apifund]`.
- Then use `some()` method on `[apitrans,apifund]` and check if any of them have `id` equal the current element using Helper Function.

```js
var arr=[ { id: "trans", amount: "100", fee: 2 }, { id: "fund", amount: "200", fee: 2 } ]

var apitrans = {success: true,id: "trans",tamount: "2000",fee: "12"}
var apifund = { success: false, id: "fund", tamount: "4000", fee: "10" }

const func = (obj1,obj2) => obj1.id === obj2.id && obj2.success

const res = arr.filter(x => [apitrans,apifund].some(a => func(x,a)));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks , but what if property differs, updated your answer input

Comment: @sowmiya You didn't mentioned anything like that in the question.

Comment: yes,apologies. I havent but its different scenario,

Comment: @sowmiya You should edit the question with complete information.

Comment: @sowmiya `var apiinsta = { errors: [code:""],id: "insta",tamount: "2000",fee: "12"}` is wrong because it contains array with keys. `[code:""]` array can't have key:value.

Comment: updated  code, `var apiinsta = { errors: [{code:"error.route.not.supported"}],id: "insta",tamount: "2000",fee: "12"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out your array with conditions i.e filter gives you new array instead of changing the original array

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "trans",
    amount: "100",
    fee: 2
  },
  {
    id: "fund",
    amount: "200",
    fee: 2
  }
]
var apitrans = {
  success: true,
  id: "trans",
  tamount: "2000",
  fee: "12"
}
var apifund = {
  success: false,
  id: "fund",
  tamount: "4000",
  fee: "10"
}



var filter = arr.filter(function(item) {
  //console.log(item);
  if (item.id === apitrans.id && apitrans.success) {
    return item
  }

});
console.log(filter);
```

Or if you want an original array to be modified instead of getting a new array, you can use your given approach with some update i.e

```js
var arr = [{
    id: "trans",
    amount: "100",
    fee: 2
  },
  {
    id: "fund",
    amount: "200",
    fee: 2
  }
]
var apitrans = {
  success: true,
  id: "trans",
  tamount: "2000",
  fee: "12"
}
var apifund = {
  success: false,
  id: "fund",
  tamount: "4000",
  fee: "10"
}


arr.forEach(e => {
  if (e.id === "trans" && apitrans.success == true) {
    Object.assign(e, apitrans);
  } else if (e.id === "fund" && apifund.success == true) {
    Object.assign(e, apifund);
  } else {
    // if success false remove the object.
    var index = arr.indexOf(e);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
})
console.log("resulted original arr", arr)
```